# ASP.NET Webforms, pass parameter to code behind

Tags: jquery, webforms

I have a C# function in code behind. The function needs some arguments. I can access the function using jQuery, but I don't know how to pass parameters from the client side. Any ideas would be useful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  response = <%=GetData(1,Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultGridPageSize"]))%>;

  $.each(response.Result, function(i, item) {
    var row = "<tr>";
    row += "<td>" + item.SYS_SubscriberID + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + item.FirstName + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + item.LastName + "</td>";
    row += "</tr>";
    $("#test>tbody").append(row);
  });
  
  $("#lblTotalRecords").append(response.RowsCount);
  $("#lblPageIndex").append("1");
  $("#lblPageCount").append(response.PageCount);
});
```

Comment: If you mean that you want to pass JS values to the `GetData()` method in C#, then that's not possible. `GetData()` runs on the server, JS runs on the client. I'd suggest researching the difference between client and server side, and also using AJAX to achieve what you require.

Comment: Hello Rory McCrossan, I mean exactly that you said. I know that this can't be done. I am asking for best practices to solve this issue. Do you have an AJAX Example?  Thank you!